# Nginx block all traffic with specific custom header except to some urls

Tags: nginx, networking, nginx-config

I have a service that is hosted in an internal network that is receiving traffic in port 443 (via https) behind a custom loadbalancer both from the internet but also from the internal network.

Internal network requests are coming with an extra custom header, let's call it `X-my-lb-header`.

I want to block all external incoming traffic to all uris (return an http response code), except to some specific ones.

Eg, let's say that i want to allow traffic that is coming to two endpoints `/endpoind1/` (prefix match) and `/endpoint2` actual match.

What is the best way to achieve a behaviour like this?

If my understanding is correct I need something like (not correct syntax bellow)

```
   location = /endpoind2 {
        if ($http_x_my_lb_header not exists) {
            pass
        } else {
            return 404
        }
        ... the rest of the directives
    }


   location ~ / {
        if ($http_x_my_lb_header) {
            return 404;
        }
        ... the rest of the directives
    }
```

But since else is not supported in nginx, i cannot figure out to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need that `else` at all in your examples. Putting `if ($http_x_my_lb_header) { return 404; }` at the beginning of the `location` block will block all the traffic without the `X-my-lb-header`. But as I understand you need the opposite thing?

Comment: @IvanShatsky indeed I need the opposite. If the header exists don't block or said differently, if the header doesn't exist block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need some logic like

```
if (header exists) {
    if (request URI isn't whitelisted) {
        block the request
    }
}
```

or in another words

```
if ((header exists) AND (request URI isn't whitelisted)) {
    block the request
}
```

Well, nginx don't allow nested `if` blocks (nor logical conditions). While some people inventing a really weird but creative solutions like [this one](http://rosslawley.co.uk/archive/old/2010/01/04/nginx-how-to-multiple-if-statements/) (emulating AND) or even [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/conditional-within-an-if-in-nginx?comment=42634) (emulating OR), a huge part of such a problems can be solved using [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) blocks (an extremely powerfull nginx feature).

Here is an example:

```
# get the $block variable using 'X-my-lb-header' value
map $http_x_my_lb_header $block {
    # if 'X-my-lb-header doesn't exists, get the value from another map block
    ''    $endpoint;
    # default value (if the 'X-my-lb-header' exists) will be an empty string
    # (unless not explicitly defined using 'default' keyword)
}

# get the $endpoint variable using request URI
map $uri $endpoint {
    # endpoint1 prefix matching (using regex)
    ~^/endpoint1    ''; don't block
    # endpoint2 exact matching
    /endpoint2      ''; don't block
    default         1; # block everything other
}
```

Now you can use this check in your server block (don't put it to some location, use at the `server` context):

```
if ($block) { return 404; }
```

Comment: That's super useful. I think i can mage it work using the map functionality. Thanks Ivan.